# SQL select at least two distinct values from three table joined togther

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I need some help.

My task is to find unique users which of them are working in two or more different institutions and is author of a document. Any user can work in the same institution several times.

I tried this query, it seems to be working, but does not return what I expected

```
SELECT 
    usr_users.id,
    usr_users.first_name, 
    usr_users.last_name, 
    usr_users.code,
    cls_institutions.short_name
FROM 
    elaba.usr_users, 
    elaba.usr_user_occupations, 
    elaba.cls_institutions, 
    elaba.doc_documents, 
    elaba.doc_document_authors
WHERE 
    usr_user_occupations.user_id = usr_users.id AND
    cls_institutions.id = usr_user_occupations.institution_id AND
    doc_documents.id = doc_document_authors.document_id AND
    doc_document_authors.user_id = usr_users.id
GROUP BY 
    usr_users.id, cls_institutions.short_name
HAVING
    COUNT(cls_institutions.short_name) > 2
```

This query returns also those users which work in one institution, this is result:

```
1:  52150;"Thomas";"Johnes";"University"
2:  52150;"Thomas";"Johnes";"College"
3:  52182;"Aligi";"Miqit";"University"
4:  52182;"Aligi";"Miqit";"College"
5:  52182;"Aligi";"Miqit";"ConstructionCo"
6:  52191;"Chris";"Steven";"University"
7:  52219;"Ally";"Jones";"University"
8:  52238;"Elly";"Gee";"University"
9:  52238;"Elly";"Gee";"ConstructionCo"
10: 52254;"Luigi";"Vasili";"ConstructionCo"
11: 52254;"Luigi";"Vasili";"University"
```

In 6 and 7 rows there are users with only one work place.

What am I doing wrong?

The best way for answer is to have a user list with last column showing in which institution are they working...

Or easier solution is to show duplicate users which differs only by institution.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: count(*) >= 2 in the HAVING clause?

Comment: Is that the entire result set returned by the query? There is no order by clause so records for the same user might be further on down the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correct join method and count in the having clause.

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.code, i.short_name
FROM elaba.usr_users u
INNER JOIN elaba.usr_user_occupations uo ON u.id = uo.user_id 
INNER JOIN elaba.cls_institutions i ON uo.institution_id = i.id
INNER JOIN elaba.doc_document_authors da ON u.id = da.user_id 
INNER JOIN elaba.doc_documents d ON da.document_id = d.id
GROUP BY u.id, i.short_name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```